# Create PDF file from HTML Body and Sending as mail attachment, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, pdf, attachment

I have a HTML body as a NSString and would like to send it as an pdf-attachment. I'm quite new to iOS and can't figure out how, see code below.

```
NSString* body = "<html><body>stuff</body></html>"
MCOMessageBuilder * builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];
[builder setHTMLBody:body];

MCOAttachment *pdf = ... //body to pdf
[builder addAttachment:pdf];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this github [iOS-htmltopdf](https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf).
Its working for me. 
This code create one pdf file. store that file into document directory, and attach the pdf file in mail.